# extract elements from wrappedarray in spark data frame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to extracting elements from wrapped array. But it is not working.
when i try to access to _image element it is throwing an error
Below is the schema of structure.
I have tried to flatten the image values using explode, but it is not working.

Can someone help me how to extract elements from below wrapped array.

```
root
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)

 |-- item_number: string (nullable = true)

 |-- price: double (nullable = true)

 |-- size: array (nullable = true)

 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |-- _description: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |-- color_swatch: array (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)

 |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)

 |    |    |    |    |-- _image: string (nullable = true)
```

**eg of below given data of nested array**

```
[[Medium,WrappedArray([Red,red_cardigan.jpg],Burgundy,burgundy_cardigan.jpg])],

[Large,WrappedArray([Red,red_cardigan.jpg], [Burgundy,burgundy_cardigan.jpg])]]
```

**code**

```
  val flatDF1 = 
  xmlDF.select(col("_description").as("description"),col("_product_image").
  as("product_image"),

  col("catalog_item._gender").as("gender"),

  col("catalog_item.item_number").as("item_number"),col("catalog_item.price").as("price"),

  col("catalog_item.size").as("size"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode is the right built-in function to use.

Given the following structure and supposing you want to use Dataframe API :

```
case class ColorSwatch(_VALUE: String, _image: String)
case class Size(_description: String, color_swatch: Seq[ColorSwatch])
case class Cart(gender: String, item_number: String, price: Double, size: Seq[Size])
```

we can write :

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
val df = sparkSession.emptyDataset[Cart].toDF

df.select(explode($"size").as("size_elem"))
      .select(explode($"size_elem.color_swatch").as("color_elem"))
      .select($"color_elem._image")
      .show(false)
```

Here I'm only selecting the image element but we can also retrieve all related attributes (gender, description, _value, ...)

Note : You can also use the Dataset API with a functional approach (consisting in flatMapping your structures)